# SQL Sentry Plan Explorer - Execution Mode in plan diagram?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

Does Plan Explorer show the Execution Mode (estimated/actual) in the plan diagram when hovering over an operator? I'm not able to find it. I do see it in the Plan Tree and Top Operations pane.

Below is SSMS where it is shown vs Plan Explorer where it is not.

[image: SSMS]
[image: Plan Explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan Explorer 19.0 has this feature, along with sexy new icons. Now there is an overlay for BatchMode operations. See [Plan Explorer release notes](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/features-fixes-sentryone-plan-explorer-19-0/) for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't show it in the plan diagram tooltip but in the plan tree tab, go to column chooser and select estimated and actual execution mode.

[image]